# Bubble Sort Visualizer problem with resizing and pressing button

Tags: arrays, reactjs, visualization, bubble-sort

I'm making Bubble Sort visualizer in React.

I've already done it and it's working, but what i want is that it is responsive so i am making that number of bars would shrink, i am doing it by dividing width and 14, because width of one bar is 8px and margin-right is 6px, but when i click button it wont work until i resize it, when i resize it then it will work

Here is my component SortingVisualization.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import bubbleSort from "../algorithms/bubbleSort";

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

class SortingVisualizer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      list: [],
      numberOfBars: 100,
      widthOfBars: 8,
      width: 0,
      height: 0,
    };

    this.bubbleSortImp = this.bubbleSortImp.bind(this);
    this.updateWindowDimensions = this.updateWindowDimensions.bind(this);
    this.updateNumberOfBars = this.updateNumberOfBars.bind(this);
    this.randomArray = this.randomArray.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.updateWindowDimensions();
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.updateWindowDimensions);
    this.updateNumberOfBars();
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.updateNumberOfBars);
    this.randomArray();
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.randomArray);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("resize", this.updateWindowDimensions);
    window.removeEventListener("resize", this.updateNumberOfBars);
    window.removeEventListener("resize", this.randomArray);
  }
  updateWindowDimensions() {
    this.setState({ width: window.innerWidth, height: window.innerHeight });
  }

  updateNumberOfBars() {
    let num = Math.floor(this.state.width / 15);
    this.setState({ numberOfBars: num });
  }

  randomArray() {
    let arr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.numberOfBars; i++) {
      arr.push(this.randomNumber());
    }

    this.setState({ list: [...arr] });
  }

  randomNumber() {
    let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;

    return randomIndex;
  }
  async bubbleSortImp(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    let arr = this.state.list;
    let len = this.state.list.length;

    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.numberOfBars; i++) {
      await sleep(50);
      bubbleSort(arr, 0, len - 1);
      this.setState({ list: [...arr] });
    }
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.numberOfBars);
    console.log(this.state.width);
    return (
      <>
        <div className="sortingVisualizer">
          {this.state.list.map((number, index) => (
            <div
              key={index}
              style={{
                height: `${number}` * 5,
                width: this.state.widthOfBars,
              }}
              className="visualize"
            ></div>
          ))}
        </div>
        <div className="buttons">
          <button className="btn" onClick={this.bubbleSortImp}>
            Bubble Sort
          </button>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default SortingVisualizer;
```

Here is my bubbleSort.js

```
let i = 0;
let j = 0;

const bubbleSort = (arr) => {
  if (i < arr.length) {
    for (let j = 0; j < arr.length - i - 1; j++) {
      let a = arr[j];
      let b = arr[j + 1];
      if (a > b) {
        swap(arr, j, j + 1);
      }
    }
  }
  i++;
};

const swap = (arr, a, b) => {
  let temp = arr[a];
  arr[a] = arr[b];
  arr[b] = temp;
};

export default bubbleSort;
```

Here is video what is happening

https://streamable.com/0kk5yt

Here is GitHub Repo
https://github.com/sk0le/sorting-visualization

Answer (score 1):

I found few issues in your implementation and modified the code accordingly. Please refer the below component code and the helper bubbleSort code as well. Hope this helps in resolving your issue.

Initially the sorting was not working because in `componentDidMount` you were setting the `numberOfBars` using the computed `width` but by that time the width didn't get updated in the state, hence the default value is `0`. This is making `numberOfBars` to `0`.

And in the utility method, sorting is not happening once the `i >= array.lenth` as the value is not reset to `0`. Found these issues and updated the code accordingly.

Below is the updated code for `SortingVisualizer`,

```js
//SortingVisualizer.js

import React, { Component } from "react";
import bubbleSort from "../algorithms/bubbleSort";

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

class SortingVisualizer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      list: [],
      numberOfBars: 100,
      widthOfBars: 8,
      width: window.innerWidth,
      height: window.innerHeight
    };

    this.bubbleSortImp = this.bubbleSortImp.bind(this);
    this.updateWindowDimensions = this.updateWindowDimensions.bind(this);
    this.randomArray = this.randomArray.bind(this);
  }

  getDerivedStateFromProps = (nextProps, prevState) => {
    if (
      prevState.width !== window.innerWidth ||
      prevState.height !== window.innerHeight
    ) {
      return {
        width: window.innerWidth,
        height: window.innerHeight
      };
    }
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.updateWindowDimensions();
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.updateWindowDimensions);
    this.randomArray();
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.randomArray);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("resize", this.updateWindowDimensions);
    window.removeEventListener("resize", this.randomArray);
  }
  updateWindowDimensions() {
    const width = window.innerWidth;
    let num = Math.floor(width / 15);
    this.setState(() => ({
      width,
      height: window.innerHeight,
      numberOfBars: num
    }));
  }

  randomArray() {
    let arr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.numberOfBars; i++) {
      arr.push(this.randomNumber());
    }

    this.setState(() => ({ list: [...arr] }));
  }

  randomNumber() {
    let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;

    return randomIndex;
  }
  async bubbleSortImp(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    let arr = this.state.list;
    let len = this.state.list.length;

    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.numberOfBars; i++) {
      await sleep(50);
      bubbleSort(arr, 0, len - 1);
      this.setState(() => ({ list: [...arr] }));
    }
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.numberOfBars);
    console.log(this.state.width);
    return (
      <>
        <div className="sortingVisualizer">
          {this.state.list.map((number, index) => (
            <div
              key={index}
              style={{
                height: `${number}` * 5,
                width: this.state.widthOfBars
              }}
              className="visualize"
            ></div>
          ))}
        </div>
        <div className="buttons">
          <button className="btn" onClick={this.bubbleSortImp}>
            Bubble Sort
          </button>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default SortingVisualizer;
```

Below is the updated code for the utility `bubbleSort`

```js
let i = 0;
let j = 0;

const bubbleSort = arr => {
  if (i < arr.length) {
    for (let j = 0; j < arr.length - i - 1; j++) {
      let a = arr[j];
      let b = arr[j + 1];
      if (a > b) {
        swap(arr, j, j + 1);
      }
    }
  } else {
    i = 0;
    return;
  }
  i++;
};

const swap = (arr, a, b) => {
  let temp = arr[a];
  arr[a] = arr[b];
  arr[b] = temp;
};

export default bubbleSort;
```